# How do I send e-mail from an aliased domain via Office365?

Tags: email, microsoft-office-365

I have a Office365 account with out own domain (a.com) and we have added a second domain (b.com) Both domains receives mail just fine.

How do I let the users choose which domain they should send from?

I want the user to be able to choose the "From" address when they send an e-mail message.

I have found a lot of how-to's but they all require the setup of additional accouints which in my view seems overly complex.

Any suggestions are most welcome!

Answer (score 1):

If you add the email user@b.com to the user account when he starts a new mail message he can choose to see the "From" field and input the mail user@b.com

From that point on he can always choose that address without having to type it.

He will also receive messages sent to user@b.com because that email is configured on his account.